# Flex Mobile - TileLayout performance issues

Tags: apache-flex, list, mobile, tiles, flex-mobile

I'm building mobile application for tablet devices. 
I have huge performance issue with List component with tile layout.
I'm showing pages with around 20-24 items on the screen and the user can scroll trough the pages. Unfortunately the list component generates the new page extremely slow. 
Overall I tested standalone List with tile layout and it's performance in every scenario is extremely slow (I have tested it on iPad1 & iPad2 ).
Please advice if you know some solution to the problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the Tile is very slow in flex. This is because it allows variable size for each item renderer and the measure / updateDisplayList takes a lot of time.

1. I would suggest you use a custom (own made) tile list and drop the flex component in this case. If you use it just for layout you can manually/programaticaly compute the positions of each item in the tile and move it to right x/y pixel.
2. Also be careful with effects! They may work ok in an AIR simulator or in the desktop browser but eat a lot of resources on mobile devices.
3. If you still want to go for the flex tile component, and not create your own tile control, then I suggest you use fixed with renderers for all items you display inside, and also specify columnWidth and rowHeight inside the TileList declatation. This may improve a little the performance... :)

Also positing some sample code does not hurt. Maybe you are doing somethig wrong somehwre... donno: extra invalidation, bad rendering etc...!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm going to write my own component.
After some debugging I find out that more instances of the itemRenderer are created and that's the heavy part.
It takes about 20 sek to create 70 instances, and they are pretty simple, like the IconItemRenderer.

Comment: I suggest you use just some simple 2d math to position your renderers / IconLoader. I know it;s easier to just use existing control, but this is not hard to implement and will be super fast ;)  Btw what is the device you are testing on ?

Comment: The devices are iPad 1 and iPad 2.
Yes are run a test where i have exchanged TiledLayout for UIComonent which create sprites and position them, the difference is undesirable.

Comment: Hello @ChavdarSlavov, I am not sure I understand your comment ?! Is it better with custom component or there is not difference ?

Comment: It's way better, but you have to use base components like Sprite and UIComponent. Probably the calucations done by TileLayout are the bottle neck but with the low level components the application just flies.

Comment: Perfect! For sure AIR apps on iOS work perfect, but the idea is to us as much as possible low level/ base classes. for example using an mx:Datagrid into a mobile app is a performance killer. Same with TileList. Suggestion: try to create own components that come from Sprite/UIComponent else try extend base components from spark (skinning is faster and looks better)

Comment: @Chavdar, can you please share with us your custom tile layout, that you built on top of low level components?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while so I don't remember specifics. Here is the code that I used but please keep in mind, that the components I wrote are are for specific purpose and include some bad practices to accomplish a specific problem for very short time. However I hope to be useful.

**pagedList**

```
package components.pagedList
{
    import components.pagedList.vo.PageItemVo;      
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.IList;
    import mx.core.IFactory;
    import mx.core.UIComponentGlobals;
    import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
    import mx.events.CollectionEventKind;

    import spark.components.List;
    import spark.layouts.HorizontalLayout;

/**
 * 
 */
public class PagedList extends List
{


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Constructor
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------        

    public function PagedList()
    {
        super();
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Variables
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    /**
     * Dimentions for the inner items should be specifyed because 
     * this component needs to know how many items can be placed in 
     * one page, but don't have the ability to create this items.
     * Default value is 1 to avoid division by zero.
     */
    public var innerItemWidth:Number = 1;

    public var innerItemHeight:Number = 1;

    /**
     * When inner item dimentions are set the component calculates how many items 
     * (per row and col) can be shown on one scren and pass these data to the page 
     * trough the dataProvider for the page.
     */
    private var pageRowCount:int = 1;

    private var pageColCount:int = 1;   

    /**
     * Count of the items that can fit in one page.
     * This count is used to slice the data into picies
     * with the same length. 
     */
    private var itemsPerPage:int = 0;   

    /**
     * Original data provider is saved here so we can re-slice it when
     * size change occure and listen for data change event.
     * 
     * TODO: implement the data chage listener
     */
    private var _originalDataProvider:IList;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private var cachedUnscaledWidth:Number = 0;
    private var cachedUnscaledHeight:Number = 0;

    //----------------------------------
    //  Custom tiles data
    //----------------------------------

    private var _customTilesData:Array;

    private var customTilesDataChanged:Boolean;

    public function set customTilesData(value:Array):void
    {
        _customTilesData = value;
        customTilesDataChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    public function get customTilesData():Array
    {
        return _customTilesData;
    }

    //----------------------------------
    //  dataProvider
    //----------------------------------

    private var originalDataProviderChanged:Boolean;

    [Inspectable(category="Data")]  
    /**
     * 
     */
    override public function set dataProvider(value:IList):void
    {
        if (_originalDataProvider)
            _originalDataProvider.removeEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, originalDataProvider_collectionChangeHandler);     

        originalDataProviderChanged = true;

        if (value)
            value.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, originalDataProvider_collectionChangeHandler, false, 0, true);

        _originalDataProvider = value;
        updatePagedData();
    }   

    /**
     * 
     */
    private function originalDataProvider_collectionChangeHandler(event:CollectionEvent):void
    {
        //trace('data changed:', event.kind, 'location:', event.location);
        if (event.kind == CollectionEventKind.REPLACE)
        {
            updateReplacedItem(event.location);
        }

    }   

    /**
     * 
     */
    private function updateReplacedItem(index:int):void
    {
        if (dataProvider)
        {
            var pageNumber:int = int(index / itemsPerPage);
            var itemIndex:int = index - (pageNumber * itemsPerPage);
            if (dataProvider[pageNumber])
            {
                var pageData:PageItemVo = PageItemVo(dataProvider[pageNumber])
                pageData.data[itemIndex] = _originalDataProvider[index];
            }
        }
    }   

    //----------------------------------
    //  innerItemRenderer
    //----------------------------------

    private var _innerItemRenderer:IFactory;

    private var innerItemRendererChanged:Boolean;

    public function set innerItemRenderer(value:IFactory):void
    {
        _innerItemRenderer = value;
        innerItemRendererChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    public function get innerItemRenderer():IFactory
    {
        return _innerItemRenderer;
    }


    //----------------------------------
    //  gaps
    //----------------------------------    

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function set verticalGap(value:Number):void
    {
        _verticalGap = value;
        gapsChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    public function get verticalGap():Number
    {
        return _verticalGap;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function set horizontalGap(value:Number):void
    {
        _horizontalGap = value;
        gapsChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    public function get horizontalGap():Number
    {
        return _horizontalGap;
    }

    private var _verticalGap:Number;

    private var _horizontalGap:Number;

    private var gapsChanged:Boolean;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Overridden methods
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    protected function updatePagedData():void
    {
        if (_originalDataProvider)
        {
            var pagedData:IList = createPagedData(_originalDataProvider);
            super.dataProvider = pagedData;
            invalidateProperties();
        }
    }

    private function createPagedData(value:IList):IList
    {
        var nestedData:Array = [];
        var dataList:Array = value.toArray();
        var pageData:PageItemVo;
        if (itemsPerPage)
        {
            var customTilesCount:int = customTilesData ? customTilesData.length : 0;
            var normalItemsPerPage:int = itemsPerPage - customTilesCount;
            while (dataList.length)
            {
                pageData = new PageItemVo();
                var data:Array = dataList.splice(0, normalItemsPerPage);
                for (var i:int = 0 ; i < customTilesCount ; i++)
                {
                    data.push( customTilesData[i] );
                }
                pageData.data = new ArrayCollection( data );
                pageData.colsCount = pageColCount;
                pageData.rowsCount = pageRowCount;
                pageData.itemWidth = innerItemWidth
                pageData.itemHeight = innerItemHeight;
                pageData.horizontalGap = horizontalGap;
                pageData.verticalGap = verticalGap;
                pageData.innerItemRenderer = _innerItemRenderer;
                nestedData.push(pageData);
            }
        }
        return new ArrayCollection(nestedData);     
    }   

    //----------------------------------
    //  Component lifecycle
    //----------------------------------    

    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        if (gapsChanged || innerItemRendererChanged || customTilesDataChanged)
        {
            updatePagedData();
            gapsChanged = false;
            innerItemRendererChanged = false;
            customTilesDataChanged = false;
        }       
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        caluclateItemsPerPage(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        // We have to update the dataProvider so it can re-slice the pages 
        // in case of orientation rotation or some other resize
        if (_originalDataProvider)
            if ( cachedUnscaledWidth != unscaledWidth || cachedUnscaledHeight != unscaledHeight )
                dataProvider = _originalDataProvider;

        cachedUnscaledWidth = unscaledWidth;
        cachedUnscaledHeight = unscaledHeight;
    }

    protected function caluclateItemsPerPage(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        var myLayout:HorizontalLayout = HorizontalLayout(layout);
        var horizontalPaddings:Number = myLayout.paddingLeft + myLayout.paddingRight;
        var verticalPaddings:Number = myLayout.paddingTop + myLayout.paddingRight;
        pageRowCount = (unscaledHeight - verticalPaddings) / (innerItemHeight + verticalGap);
        pageColCount = (unscaledWidth - horizontalPaddings) / (innerItemWidth + horizontalGap);
        itemsPerPage = pageRowCount * pageColCount; 
    }   


}
}
```

**PageItemRenderer**

```
package skins.pagedList
{
    import components.pagedList.vo.PageItemVo;

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.core.IDataRenderer;
    import mx.core.IFactory;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    import spark.components.IItemRenderer;



//--------------------------------------
//  Events
//--------------------------------------

/**
 *  Dispatched when the <code>data</code> property changes.
 *
 *  <p>When you use a component as an item renderer,
 *  the <code>data</code> property contains the data to display.
 *  You can listen for this event and update the component
 *  when the <code>data</code> property changes.</p>
 * 
 *  @eventType mx.events.FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE
 */
[Event(name="dataChange", type="mx.events.FlexEvent")]  





/**
 * 
 * ASDoc comments for this item renderer class
 * 
 */
public class PageItemRenderer extends UIComponent
    implements IDataRenderer, IItemRenderer
{





    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Constructor
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------        

    public function PageItemRenderer()
    {
        super();
        cacheAsBitmap = true;
    }   



    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Variables 
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------
    //  data
    //----------------------------------

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    private var _data:PageItemVo;

    private var dataChanged:Boolean;

    [Bindable("dataChange")]

    /**
     *  The implementation of the <code>data</code> property
     *  as defined by the IDataRenderer interface.
     *  When set, it stores the value and invalidates the component 
     *  to trigger a relayout of the component.
     */
    public function get data():Object
    {
        return _data;
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        _data = PageItemVo(value);
        colCount = _data.colsCount;
        rowCount = _data.rowsCount;
        itemWidth = _data.itemWidth;
        itemHeight = _data.itemHeight;
        horizontalGap = _data.horizontalGap;
        verticalGap = _data.verticalGap;
        innerItemRenderer = _data.innerItemRenderer;
        _tilesData = ArrayCollection(_data.data);

        dataChanged = true;

        if (hasEventListener(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE))
            dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));

        invalidateProperties();
    }   

    //----------------------------------
    //  gaps
    //----------------------------------    

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function set verticalGap(value:Number):void
    {
        _verticalGap = value;
        gapsChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    public function get verticalGap():Number
    {
        return _verticalGap;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function set horizontalGap(value:Number):void
    {
        _horizontalGap = value;
        gapsChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    public function get horizontalGap():Number
    {
        return _horizontalGap;
    }   

    private var _verticalGap:Number = 5;    

    private var _horizontalGap:Number = 5;

    private var gapsChanged:Boolean;


    //----------------------------------
    //  itemIndex
    //----------------------------------

    private var _itemIndex:int;

    public function get itemIndex():int
    {
        return _itemIndex;
    }

    public function set itemIndex(value:int):void
    {
        if (value == _itemIndex)
            return;

        invalidateDisplayList();
        _itemIndex = value;
    }       

    //----------------------------------
    //  showsCaret
    //----------------------------------

    private var _showsCaret:Boolean = false;

    public function get showsCaret():Boolean
    {
        return _showsCaret;
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */    
    public function set showsCaret(value:Boolean):void
    {
        if (value == _showsCaret)
            return;

        _showsCaret = value;
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }


    //----------------------------------
    //  selected
    //----------------------------------

    private var _selected:Boolean = false;

    public function get selected():Boolean
    {
        return _selected;
    }

    public function set selected(value:Boolean):void
    {
        if (value == _selected)
            return;

        _selected = value; 
    }


    //----------------------------------
    //  dragging
    //----------------------------------

    private var _dragging:Boolean = false;

    public function get dragging():Boolean
    {
        return _dragging;
    }

    public function set dragging(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _dragging = value;
    }   

    //----------------------------------
    //  label
    //----------------------------------

    private var _label:String;

    public function get label():String
    {
        return _label;
    }

    /**
     *  @private  
     */
    public function set label(value:String):void
    {
        _label = value;
    }       

    //----------------------------------
    //  item properties
    //----------------------------------

    /**
     * Dimentions for the inner items should be specifyed because 
     * this component needs to know how many items can be placed in 
     * one page, but don't have the ability to create this items.
     * Default value is 1 to avoid division by zero.
     */
    public var itemWidth:Number = 1;

    public var itemHeight:Number = 1;

    /**
     * When inner item dimentions are set the component calculates how many items 
     * (per row and col) can be shown on one scren and pass these data to the page 
     * trough the dataProvider for the page.
     */
    public var rowCount:int = 1;

    public var colCount:int = 1;        

    private var _tilesData:ArrayCollection;

    private var sizeChanged:Boolean;

    private var _tileContainer:UIComponent;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private var innerItemRenderer:IFactory;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Overridden methods
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------
    //  Component lifecycle
    //----------------------------------        

    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        super.commitProperties();

        if (dataChanged)
        {
            dataChanged = false;
            createTiledContent();
        }
        if (gapsChanged)
        {
            createTiledContent();
        }
    }

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        super.measure();

        measuredMinHeight = measuredWidth =  parent.width;
        measuredMinHeight = measuredHeight = parent.height;
    }   

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                                  unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        var tileCntWidth:Number = colCount * (itemWidth + horizontalGap);
        _tileContainer.x = 0.5 * (unscaledWidth - tileCntWidth);
    }






    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Methods
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    protected function createTiledContent():void
    {
        clearChildren();
        _tileContainer = new UIComponent();
        var itemsCount:int = _tilesData.length;
        var row:int, col:int, item:DisplayObject;
        for (var i:int = 0 ; i < itemsCount ; i++ )
        {
            row = int( i / colCount );
            col = i - row * colCount;
            if (_tilesData[i].hasOwnProperty("itemFactory"))
            {
                item = IFactory(_tilesData[i].itemFactory).newInstance();
            }
            else
            {
                item =  innerItemRenderer.newInstance();
            }
            Object(item).data = _tilesData[i];
            item.x = col * (itemWidth + horizontalGap);
            item.y = row * (itemHeight + verticalGap);
            _tileContainer.addChild(item);
        }
        addChild(_tileContainer);
        invalidateSize();
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Helper methods
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    private function clearChildren():void
    {
        var numChildren:int = this.numChildren;
        for (var i:int = 0 ; i < numChildren ; i++ )
        {
            this.removeChildAt(0);
        }
    }       

}
}
```

**PagedItemVo**

```
package components.pagedList.vo
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    import mx.collections.IList;
    import mx.core.IFactory;

    [Bindable]
    public class PageItemVo extends EventDispatcher
    {

        public var data:IList;

        public var rowsCount:int;

        public var colsCount:int;

        public var itemWidth:Number;

        public var itemHeight:Number;

        public var verticalGap:Number;

        public var horizontalGap:Number;

        public var innerItemRenderer:IFactory;

        public function PageItemVo(target:IEventDispatcher=null)
        {
            super(target);
        }
    }
}
```

**ScrollingListSkin**

```
package skins.pagedList
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    import mx.core.DPIClassification;
    import mx.core.ScrollPolicy;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.events.TouchInteractionEvent;

    import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
    import spark.events.RendererExistenceEvent;
    import spark.skins.mobile.ListSkin;
    import spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses.MobileSkin;

    public class ScrollingListSkin extends ListSkin
    {
        private var pageIndicator:Sprite;
        private var indicatorSize:uint;
        private var _isHorizontal:Boolean;
        private var _suspendPageIndicatorShortcut:Boolean;

        public function ScrollingListSkin()
        {
            super();

            switch (applicationDPI)
            {
                case DPIClassification.DPI_320:
                {
                    indicatorSize = 32;
                    break;
                }
                case DPIClassification.DPI_240:
                {
                    indicatorSize = 24;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    indicatorSize = 16;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Overridden methods
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            scroller.setStyle("skinClass", PagedListScrollerSkin);

            // page indicator
            pageIndicator = new Sprite();

            // TODO (jasonsj): extend pageIndicator hit area to use the entire 
            // width/height of the List as a shortcut. Currently this only works
            // in the tiny area where the indicators are.
            //pageIndicator.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pageIndicaterMouseHandler);
            //pageIndicator.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, pageIndicaterMouseHandler);
            //pageIndicator.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, pageIndicaterMouseHandler);

            addChild(pageIndicator);

            // listen for changes to the list
            dataGroup.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, dataGroupUpdateComplete);
            scroller.addEventListener(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START, touchInteractionStart);
            scroller.addEventListener(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_END, positionChanged);
        }

        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            // isHorizontal
            /*var hScrollPolicy:Boolean = getStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy") == ScrollPolicy.ON;
            var vScrollPolicy:Boolean = getStyle("verticalScrollPolicy") == ScrollPolicy.ON;
            _isHorizontal = hScrollPolicy && !vScrollPolicy;*/
            _isHorizontal = true;
        }

        override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.drawBackground(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var pos:Number = (isHorizontal) ? scroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition :
                scroller.viewport.verticalScrollPosition;
            var viewportSize:Number = (isHorizontal) ? scroller.viewport.width :
                scroller.viewport.height;

            var selectedIndex:int = Math.round(pos / viewportSize);
            var numElements:int = dataGroup.numElements;

            var g:Graphics = pageIndicator.graphics;
            g.clear();

            // if we have only one page there shouldn't be any scrollbar visuals
            if (numElements == 1) return;

            var axisPos:Number = 0;
            var centerPos:Number = indicatorSize / 2;
            var radius:Number = indicatorSize / 4;
            //TODO: make so the color could be specifyed outisde 
            var selectionColor:Number = 0x000000; //getStyle("selectionColor");


            //var elementsPerPage:int = Math.floor(unscaledWidth/FileIconItemRenderer.ITEM_WIDTH) * Math.floor(unscaledHeight/FileIconItemRenderer.ITEM_HEIGHT);

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            {
                if (i == selectedIndex)
                    g.beginFill(selectionColor, 1);
                else
                    g.beginFill(0, .25);

                if (isHorizontal)
                    g.drawCircle(axisPos + centerPos, centerPos, radius);
                else
                    g.drawCircle(centerPos, axisPos + centerPos, radius);

                g.endFill();

                axisPos += indicatorSize;
            }

            var pageIndicatorX:Number = (isHorizontal) ? (unscaledWidth - axisPos) / 2 :
                unscaledWidth - (indicatorSize * 1.5);
            var pageIndicatorY:Number = (isHorizontal) ? unscaledHeight - (indicatorSize * 1.5):
                (unscaledHeight - axisPos) / 2;

            setElementPosition(pageIndicator, Math.floor(pageIndicatorX), Math.floor(pageIndicatorY));
        }

        override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
        {
            super.styleChanged(styleProp);

            var allStyles:Boolean = !styleProp || styleProp == "styleName";

            if (allStyles || styleProp == "horizontalScrollPolicy" ||
                styleProp == "verticalScrollPolicy")
            {
                invalidateProperties();
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        }

        private function get isHorizontal():Boolean
        {
            return _isHorizontal;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  Event Handlers
        //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private function dataGroupUpdateComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            invalidateDisplayList();
        }

        private function touchInteractionStart(event:TouchInteractionEvent):void
        {
            _suspendPageIndicatorShortcut = true;
        }

        private function positionChanged(event:TouchInteractionEvent):void
        {
            invalidateDisplayList();
            _suspendPageIndicatorShortcut = false;
        }

        private function pageIndicaterMouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (_suspendPageIndicatorShortcut)
                return;

            // Mouse events on the pageIndicator sprite will jump to the selected page
            var pos:Number = (isHorizontal) ? event.localX : event.localY;
            var size:Number = (isHorizontal) ? pageIndicator.width : pageIndicator.height;

            pos = Math.min(Math.max(pos, 0), size) - (indicatorSize / 2);

            var viewportSize:Number = (isHorizontal) ? scroller.viewport.width : scroller.viewport.height;
            viewportSize = viewportSize * dataGroup.numElements;

            var viewportPosition:Number = (pos / size) * viewportSize;

            if (isHorizontal)
                scroller.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition = viewportPosition;
            else
                scroller.viewport.verticalScrollPosition = viewportPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
<pagedList:PagedList id="displayList" 
                 width="100%" height="100%"
                 itemRenderer="skins.pagedList.PageItemRenderer"
                 innerItemRenderer="components.pagedList.tiles.FolderTileItem"
                 innerItemWidth="146" innerItemHeight="150"
                 skinClass="skins.pagedList.ScrollingListSkin"
                 verticalScrollPolicy="off"
                 horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
                 pageScrollingEnabled="true"
                 horizontalGap="15" verticalGap="20"
                 contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
                 selectionColor="0xFFFFFF">
<pagedList:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout columnWidth="{displayList.width}" 
                        variableColumnWidth="false" 
                        gap="0"
                        paddingTop="30"/>
</pagedList:layout>
```

Unfortunatly I can't share the FolderTileItem source with you, but its simple a simple component that extends Sprite.